# test maven web module in eclipse and tomcat

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, tomcat, maven

I have a maven web module in my eclipse project.
Is it possible to simply test this module in eclipse by running it on tomcat.
At the minute im generating a war file and adding it to the webapps directory of tomcat.

A quicker approach would be great

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to simply test this module in eclipse by running it on tomcat.

You could deploy your application on Tomcat using the WTP. This is doable whether you're using the [Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/wtp.html) or the [m2eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html) (just make sure to install the *Maven Integration for WTP* from the *m2eclipse Extras*).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you try the maven jetty plugin.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/rapid-testing-jetty6-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

If you could accept to use Jetty to test it , 
it's more easier to use Eclipse Run-Jetty-Run Plugin to run your project , just one click without any configuration!

Reference 
http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/